# Why am I getting a blank window with guizero?

Tags: python, python-3.x, guizero

I'm simply trying to run the simplest of programs just to make it work, but I keep getting a window with a black background with nothing in it. I've tried changing the background color but nothing seems to work?

```
from guizero import App, Text, TextBox, PushButton

app = App("Hello world", bg = "white")

welcome_message = Text(app, text="Welcome to my app", size=40, font="Times New Roman", color="white")
my_name = TextBox(app)
update_text = PushButton(app, command=say_my_name, text="Display my name")

app.display()
```

[image]

Comment: I edited the title to describe the problem you're having. For reference, see [ask]: "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem". If you'd like to make any further changes, you can [edit] it yourself of course.

Comment: I have the same problem! this issue happens on a mac, when I run the same code on a raspberry pi, I can see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you’re using an [outdated version of tkinter](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/):

You could check for this in your version of Python3:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter.TkVersion
8.5
```

If you see 8.5, then you need to install your own version of Python that uses tkinter 8.6 or higher. You could install 3.9.8 or 3.10 from the link above, but if you want newer versions, you could use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)’s Python. Or if you want a different way, [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) is probably the simplest.

Once you get pyenv set up, it’s as simple as:

```
pyenv install 3.9.14
pyenv global 3.9.14
pip3 install guizero
```

Use `pyenv install -l` to see if there’s a newer version you could use.

Answer (score 0):

In line 9, don't use keyword `text` in `Pushbutton`. I also changed variable in line 6 `my_name` to `text`.

```
from guizero import App, Text, TextBox, PushButton

def say_my_name():
    text.value = 'hello world' 
    
app = App(title='hello world', bg="blue")
welcome_message = Text(app, text="Welcome to my app", size=10, font="Times New Roman", color="white")
text = TextBox(app)
button = PushButton(app, command=say_my_name)

app.display()
```

Comment: If you add keyword. it will get blank. Just testing on my Raspberry Pi 4B 4/8Gb

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to call **say_my_name** without defining it first. You've also set **welcome_message** and the **apps** background to the same color.

```
from guizero import App, Text, TextBox, PushButton, info
app = App("Hello world", bg = "white")


def say_my_name():
    #Change to do what you want
    #my_name.value gives you the text value of myname after you use the pushbutton  
    app.info("User greeting", "welcome "+my_name.value)


welcome_message = Text(app, text="Welcome to my app", size=40, font="Times New Roman", color="Black")
my_name = TextBox(app)
update_text = PushButton(app, command=say_my_name, text="Display my name")


app.display()
```